# Plugin Installation Error

Tags: plugins, errors

> Unpacking the package…
>
> Could not create directory.
>
> Return to Plugin Installer

When I install the plugin it shows this message.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory. Set it to 777 and install again. Reset it to 755 after that.

Comment: sir i have try for it but not responce